# Can't use the derivative function found with sympy.diff

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to use the derivative function found using `sympy.diff` to calculate other values. For some reason I get this message when I try my code:

> ValueError: First variable cannot be a number: 4

Here is my code:

```
import sympy as sp

def f(x):
    return (x**2-3)/2

x = sp.Symbol('x')

def df(x):
    return sp.diff(f(x), x, 1)

print('la dérivée de f(x) est:', df(x))
print(df(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in `print(df(4))` you are passing the number 4 to `df` which passes it to `sp.diff` like `sp.diff(f(4), 4, 1)`.

You meant to pass `sp.Symbol('x')` to `sp.diff` which then will return a function (= the derivative of `f` with respect to `x`) which *to that* you can pass the number 4 (= evaluate at `x = 4`).

```
import sympy as sp

def f(x):
    return (x**2-3)/2

x = sp.Symbol('x')

def df(x):
    return sp.diff(f(x), x, 1)

print('la dérivée de f(x) est:', df(x))
print(df(x)(4))  # note the additional (x) here
```